# Error: failed to get recent blockhash: FetchError: request to https://api.devnet.solana.com/ failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 31.13.69.169:443

Tags: solana-program, devnet

when I run the template code from [solana-movie-client](https://github.com/Unboxed-Software/solana-movie-client), I've got the error.
[image]

MacOs

Node v16.20.2

Npm 8.19.4

Comment: This looks like a normal connection timeout error, given by `ETIMEDOUT` in the screenshot. Be sure that your machine has an active connection to the internet and can make requests.